# How can I divide every element of my list by five and round the results?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list called “sum” which contains integer values between 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. I want to make another list called “average” which contains the average value by dividing every element of the sum list by 5 and add the results to the same element of the average list.

My problem is I am using the code:

```
List<int> average = sum.Select(x => x/5).ToList();
```

But it does not give me a correct results as C# decides automatically how to round the result to 0 or 1. But for example when I give the results to excel, it gives me a different results.
I need to manually get every element of my sum list and divide it by five, then decide if the answer is greater or equal to 0.5, round it up to 1. And if the result is less than 0.5 round it to 0.

Comment: You are making up your own definition of what "average" means. Why? That's just extra confusion.

Comment: so you want a result list with only ones and zeros ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<int> average = sum.Select( x => (int)Math.Round(x/5.0) ).ToList();
```

However, if you really want an average of the items:

```
int average = Math.Round( sum.Average() );
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Average` returns a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var average = sum.Select(x => (int)(x / 5.0 + 0.5)).ToList();
```

or using [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var average = sum.Select(x => (int)Math.Round(x / 5.0)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var average = sum.Select(x => (x / 5.0) >= 0.5 ? 1 : 0).ToList();
```